# HP Proliant DL360 G3 - Can't boot from CD

Tags: centos, boot, hp-proliant

I have made several bootable disks: CentOS amd64, CentOS i386 and the HP SmartStart software. My second hand server refuses to boot to any of them, displaying the message: "non system disk or disk error replace and strike any key when ready"

Comment: And the BIOS is capable of doing that? And is configured accordingly?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the drive is actually functional. I've had plenty of media drives on G3 ProLiants die after 5 years or so. Do you have a USB CD/DVD you can try with?

Other than that, enter the Rom-Based Setup Utility (RBSU) and make sure the "Boot Order" is set to hit the media drive before the Smart Array controller.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have checked in the RBSU and found the "Boot Controller Order". You're right, the Smart Array controller is listed before the PCI IDE controller, but I don't seem to be able to change this order as the setting appear to be read only.

Comment: Well, that only applies to boot disk settings. If your CD/DVD is listed first in the standard Boot menu, then you have the right setup. Your drive may not work, though. Can you test with a USB unit or a drive from another server?

Comment: I have another server drive available, though that server was having the same issue as the one I'm currently testing on. I will try the drive just in case, however.

Comment: Just tried out the other drive I had available, it gives the same error, it could be possible that both drives are shot, but I believe that the servers came from an environment where they were used regularly. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm going to try a PXE boot instead. Wish me luck!

Comment: Was this resolved?

Answer (score 2):

I have HP Proliant DL360 G4 series server and it was not recognizing the portable CD/DVD ROM then I used USB external CD ROM. I changed the Booting order from USB Drive and it worked from that.

Answer (score 1):

Check the BIOS is configured to boot from the CD before the internal disks.

Comment: @Jonny Can you edit your question to include the information that's led you to that theory?